# Rust - spawning a shell fails with an error

Tags: rust

I am trying to execute a command within a shell using

```
let mut child = Command::new("ilorest")
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("ilorest command failed to start");

child
    .stdin
    .as_mut()
    .ok_or("Child process stdin has not been captured!")?
    .write_all(b"login HOST -u [USERNAME] -p [PASSWORD] \n 
    exit")?;
```

After executing this code, I am getting the error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rdmc.py", line 811, in <module>
  File "rdmc.py", line 315, in run
  File "rdmc.py", line 333, in cmdloop
  File "cliutils.py", line 194, in version
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Failed to execute script rdmc
```

I am not able to understand where I am missing?

Comment: Hi Harshit. It looks like something is missed in your example. It'll be better if you can provide a little bit more information about `ilorest` because the errors from python files doesn't look related to your rust code. As the other solution you can try to start some simple bash script from your rust code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I was missing the code

```
let output = child.wait_with_output().unwrap();
```